# Invalid file format in google play

Tags: android

I made an android application in Dreamweaver cs5.5. The bin directory showed  my.debug.apk and also my.ap_  I renamed the file my.ap_ to my.apk made a key, jarsinged, zipaligned and uploaded to google play. Everything went without a hitch. Google lists it as well. Now when I try to install it from google play it says invalid file format!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - the following link solved it for me:

http://www.acrobatmedia.net/android.html

You should not rename the file - following the signing / aligning sequence will result with the the apk being created for you

Comment: The link does rename the .ap_ to apk!